# How to get the first column of all tables using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to get all the first columns of all tables using JQuery?

The code below doesn't work in IE 6.0 as first-child is not supported there apparently:

```
$('table.tblItemTemplate  td:first-child');
```

Thanks

Comment: if this works in other browsers I would say you most likely have a mistake in your html can we see the html please. Validation goes a long way

Comment: [Doesn't seem so to me](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Ts26K/)!?

Comment: Shef, how did you test that link with IE 6.0?

Comment: @William: The way you would, fire up IE 6.0 and visit the page. How are you testing it?

Comment: I don't have IE 6.0. I usually use IETester but recently have tried setting up a microsoft vpc to test it; haven't managed to configure it properly yet.

Answer (score 5):

Edit, below is a better soltuion:

```
$('table.tblItemTemplate td:first-child').addClass('first');
```

Comment: I think you would need to iterate over `td:first` but the poster has amended it to `td:first-child` which matches the first `td` of every row.

Comment: @Wes: "below is a better solution...". that seems to be just repeat of the code in question!